# How to sort inner tables in Lua by their "score" and then "index"?

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have the following Lua table stored in the variable `T`:

```
{
    ["mn"] = { ["index"] = 7, ["key"] = "mn", ["score"] = 0 },
    ["kl"] = { ["index"] = 6, ["key"] = "kl", ["score"] = .4 },
    ["ef"] = { ["index"] = 3, ["key"] = "ef", ["score"] = .3 },
    ["ab"] = { ["index"] = 1, ["key"] = "ab", ["score"] = 0 },
    ["cd"] = { ["index"] = 2, ["key"] = "cd", ["score"] = .1 },
    ["gh"] = { ["index"] = 4, ["key"] = "gh", ["score"] = 0 },
    ["ij"] = { ["index"] = 5, ["key"] = "ij", ["score"] = .2 }
}
```

I want to sort all of the inner tables of the `T` table in the following way:
 1. Tables with higher `score` are put on the top.
 2. Tables with equal `score` are sorted by their `index`.

So, after sorting, the following sequential table should be produced on the output:

```
{
    [1] = { ["index"] = 6, ["key"] = "kl", ["score"] = .4 }, -- highest "score"
    [2] = { ["index"] = 3, ["key"] = "ef", ["score"] = .3 },
    [3] = { ["index"] = 5, ["key"] = "ij", ["score"] = .2 },
    [4] = { ["index"] = 2, ["key"] = "cd", ["score"] = .1 },
    [5] = { ["index"] = 1, ["key"] = "ab", ["score"] = 0 }, -- lowest "score", lowest "index"
    [6] = { ["index"] = 4, ["key"] = "gh", ["score"] = 0 }, -- when scores are the same, sort by their "index" instead
    [7] = { ["index"] = 7, ["key"] = "mn", ["score"] = 0 } -- lowest "score", highest "index"
}
```

How to accomplish this Lua table sort?

Comment: https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-table.sort

Comment: I understand that I have to use `table.sort` Lua function.But, I don't know how to use it for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to convert the hash you have into a table first and then sort the elements of that table using a custom sort function that sorts by `score` (descending) and then by `index` (ascending) for those elements that have the same score.

Something like this should work:

```
local hash = {
    ["mn"] = { ["index"] = 7, ["key"] = "mn", ["score"] = 0 },
    ["kl"] = { ["index"] = 6, ["key"] = "kl", ["score"] = .4 },
    ["ef"] = { ["index"] = 3, ["key"] = "ef", ["score"] = .3 },
    ["ab"] = { ["index"] = 1, ["key"] = "ab", ["score"] = 0 },
    ["cd"] = { ["index"] = 2, ["key"] = "cd", ["score"] = .1 },
    ["gh"] = { ["index"] = 4, ["key"] = "gh", ["score"] = 0 },
    ["ij"] = { ["index"] = 5, ["key"] = "ij", ["score"] = .2 }
}
local tbl = {}
for _,v in pairs(hash) do
  table.insert(tbl, v)
end
table.sort(tbl, function(a,b)
    return a.score > b.score or a.score == b.score and a.index < b.index
  end)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

In lua the table encompasses two data structures: the array and the dictionary.

Sorting means sorting array, where each element is associated with a numeric index and indices are consecutive that is: 1,2,3...

You initial table is actually a dictionary - each entry has an arbitrary key associated to it (in your case those are strings).

Thus, what you are describing is not actually a sorting task, you want a different kind of table in the end.

`table.sort` works on array part of the lua table, that is on those elements with indices starting from 1 and ending at first nil entry.

```
a={s=3,['r']=3,  5,3,2,  nil,21}
                 |these|
                 |ones |
```

So, you first create an array and sort that one:

```
local sorted={}
for k,v in pairs(T) do
  table.insert(sorted,v)
end
table.sort(sorted,function(a,b)
  --your code here
  --function should return true if element `a`  from the array `sorted`
  --must be higher (to the left of) `b`
end)
```

Alternatively, you could store the entries in the same table both in dictionary and array part, the `table.sort` function would ignore the dictionary. But it would not be wise to loop through table using `pairs` and add new elements at the same time. Thus the idiomatic way would still involve intermediate copy.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation.